# Serialize Symfony form data to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

Using [Symfony Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), **HTML** is generated that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="form_name" name="form[name]">
<input type="email" id="form_email" name="form[email]">
<textarea id="form_message" name="form[message]"></textarea>
```

With a bit of **JS** the entries are transformed to JSON and submitted:

```
const contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');

contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData));

  // handle submission... 
})
```

**JSON** that is sent to the backend:

`"{"form[name]":"John Doe","form[email]":"example@domain.com","form[message]":"Some message"}"`

In my controller (in **PHP**) I serialize the data into an array: `$data = json_decode($request->getContent());` The issue is this data is formatted (as expected) like so:

```
["form[name]" => "John Doe", "form[email]" => "example@domain.com", "form[message]" => "Some message"];
```

Is there a *built-in* way to get the following result (either in PHP or JS)?

```
[ "name" => "John Doe", "email" => "example@domain.com", "message" => "Some message" ];
```

I looked into using the [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) without success, and now wonder if I missed something or if the data should be fixed in JS before submission. Might there be a built-in solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you are submitting from using AJAX. And in that you can directly specify FormData object as body in AJAX API request. At backend you will receive data in $_POST or $_GET array as per your request method.

Here is the example code.

```js
const contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');

contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch('<AJAX API URL>', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        return Promise.reject(response);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }); 
})
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">
  <input type="text" name="form['name']" />
  <input type="text" name="form['job']" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is how you will get data in POST array.

```
Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            ['name'] => 123
            ['job'] => 123123
        )

)
```